# Expanding the square in the variance

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, solution-verification, variance

$\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{var}}$

In the Pattern Recognition book of Bishop, I'm reading the following statement, that I don't fully understand.

> The variance of $f(x)$ is defined by 
>   $$\var[f] = E[(f(x)-E[f(x)])^2]$$ 
>   Expanding out the square, we see that the variance can also be written
>   in terms of the expectations of $f(x)$ and $f(x)^2$: 
>   $$\var[f] = E[f(x)^2]-E[f(x)]^2$$

I can derive this the following way, but I'm not sure if this is correct, and if it is, why?

$$
\begin{align}
\var[f] & = E[(f(x)-E[f(x)])^2]\\[6pt]
& = E[f(x)^2-2f(x)E[f(x)]+E[f(x)]^2]\\[6pt]
& = E[f(x)^2]-E[2f(x)E[f(x)]]+E[E[f(x)]^2] \quad\text{since }E[X+Y] = E[X] + E[Y] \\[6pt]
& = E[f(x)^2]-2E[f(x)]E[f(x)]+E[E[f(x)]^2]\\[6pt]
& {}\qquad\text{since }E[cX] = cE[X],
\text{ but is $E[f(x)]$ const. here?} \\[6pt]
& = E[f(x)^2]-2E[f(x)]E[f(x)]+E[f(x)]^2 \\[6pt]
& {}\quad\quad\text{ I guess $E[E[X]] = E[X]$, or something like that?} \\[6pt]
& = E[f(x)^2]-E[f(x)]^2
\end{align}
$$

Is this correct? Are my assumptions I marked correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is correct.  $E(f(x))$ is constant since it's not random.  And $E(c)=c$ if $c$ is constant, so $E(E(f(x)))=E(f(x))$.